# CSS 3 Layout 3 columns in 1 row

Tags: html, css

i have one row where am populating 3 columns side by side like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Thjn.png). Problem is when i select a json node it will populate the tree path by adding one extra div. As a result my table is going down a bit like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjZnL.png).

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.Row
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 500px;
    table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
    border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/
}
.Column
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 400px;
    position: static;
}
.jsoneditor-outer.has-nav-bar {
    height: 500px;
}
json-editor{
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row"> 
    <div class="Column"><json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [data]="data" ></json-editor></div>
    <div class="Column"><json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [data]="data" ></json-editor></div>
    <div class="Column"><json-editor [options]="editorOptions" [data]="data" ></json-editor></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to provide working code without working code I can't solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your above CSS Code with this:

```
.Row
{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; 
    min-height: 500px;
    justify-content: stretch;
}
.Column {
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.jsoneditor-outer.has-nav-bar {
    min-height: 500px;
}
json-editor{
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Hopefully, it will work ...